# Unable to load the application sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I have copy of sugarcrm files for production. And I am also attempting to setup in localhost. I have copied the files to htdocs folder and make mysql dump. Modified the configuration changes, but when i try the url to localhost/sugar7810ent it is showing up the "Unable to load the application." error. Below is the code. Please help any?
Fallowed below link.
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Platform_Management/Migrating_From_On-Demand_to_On-Site/index.html

**Config.php**

```
'dbconfig' => 
  array (
    'db_host_name' => 'localhost',
    'db_host_instance' => '',
    'db_user_name' => 'sugarcrm',
    'db_password' => 'root',
    'db_name' => 'db_newparkmats',
    'db_type' => 'mysql',
    'db_port' => '',
    'db_manager' => 'MysqliManager',
  ),
```

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN SUGARCRM RESTRICTIONS
RedirectMatch 403 (?i).*\.log$
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+not_imported_.*\.txt
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+(soap|cache|xtemplate|data|examples|include|log4php|metadata|modules)/+.*\.(php|tpl)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+emailmandelivery\.php
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+upload
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+custom/+blowfish
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+cache/+diagnostic
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+files\.md5$
# END SUGARCRM RESTRICTIONS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sugar7810ent
    RewriteRule ^cache/jsLanguage/(.._..).js$ index.php?entryPoint=jslang&module=app_strings&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^cache/jsLanguage/(\w*)/(.._..).js$ index.php?entryPoint=jslang&module=$1&lang=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|js|css|ico)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set ETag ""
                Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
                Header set Expires "01 Jan 2112 00:00:00 GMT"
        </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is there anything in sugarcrm.log, or your php error log?

Answer (score 3):

Common issues I've encountered include

- Permissions. Way too many issues are solved by incorrect user or permissions on SugarCRM, especially around the cache.
- Missing `cache` dir. If you don't have one, just `mkdir cache` in Sugar's root directory, assign appropriate user/permissions to it, and let Sugar generate the cache
- .htaccess `RewriteBase` is wrong, although it looks like you've got that covered here
- Similarly, `config.php`'s `site_url` param is incorrect
- Apache's mod_rewrite is not enabled and/or Apache doesn't respect local .htaccess files
- Incorrect `dbconfig` settings in `config.php` -- simply try to `mysql -h localhost -u sugarcrm -proot db_newparkmats` to see if *your* config works (from the Sugar app. server)

Answer (score 0):

Another source of problems might be the Javascript files from cache (cache/javascript/base/components/_some_hash_here.js).

Backup everything to another directory and remove all the files from cache/javascript/base/components. Then try to load your app in an Incognito/Private window.